# Centroid of kmeans in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Im using kmeans function in matlab for clustering of my dataset.
Im interested in the centroid generated from the function.

During the 1st run, the centroid produced are c1,c2,c3.
During the 2nd run, the centroid produced are c2,c1,c3

For the next run, it produces the permutation of the centroid.

is there any way to produce the same permutation for every run i.e c1,c2,c3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the method used to choose the initial cluster centroid positions, sometimes known as seeds. The default option selects k observations from X at random. Read http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html

Comment: but how do i make sure it will always select the same seed for every run?

Comment: @Arun: you give the method a 'start' argument with a matrix indicating the coordinates of the seeds.

Comment: Thanks all. The following code does it. rand('seed',0);
[IDX, C] = kmeans(X',k,'start','uniform');